# Is there a way to simplify this code which aims to return an absolute value given an integer?

Tags: java, if-statement, return, boolean, assert

Is there a way to simplify this piece of code further? The codes aim is to return an absolute value given an integer.

```
public class Abs {
public static int abs(int x) {
if(x < 0) { return -x; }
if(x >= 0) { return x; }
assert false;
return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: `return x<0 ? -x : x;`

Comment: Why not `Math.abs()` ?'

Answer (score 1):

You could put this in an integer and check the condition when you assign a value.
`int y = x < 0 ? -x : x;`
Or in a method:

```
public static int abs(int x) {
return x < 0 ? -x : x;
}
```

The "assert false" will never be reached, so it is useless.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ternary operator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Java-Ternary-Operator-Examples#:%7E:text=Java%20Programming%20Java8Java%20Technologies,be%20assigned%20to%20the%20variable.) to simplify the code

```
public class Abs {
   public static int abs(int x) {
     return x < 0 ? -x : x;
   }
}
```